# Pass objects into python flask server

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing the main for my program and creating a bunch of objects and launching workers.  I want to be able pass some of the objects that I'm creating into and start my rest_server as well from this main.

For example, looking to do something like...

***EDIT BETTER EXAMPLE***
main program:

```
from restserver import launchclass

rest = launchclass(object1, object2...)
rest.launch()
```

where object1 and object2 are some object I've created in other parts of my python program from which I want to use within my rest server.

restserver:

```
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def __init__(self, object1, object2):
        self.obj1 = object1
        self.obj2 = object2

    def get(self):
        return self.object1.hello()

class launchclass():
    def __init__(self, object1, object2):
        self.obj1 = object1
        self.obj2 = object2

    def launch(self):
        api.add_resource(HelloWorld, 'www.api.com/helloworld', obj1, obj2)???
        app.run()
```

Comment: So why not just do so?  What is it that you need that you can't solve this by defining `run` like this: `def run(self, obj1, obj2): something_else.obj1 = obj1  # etc.`?  Can you add a bit more detail?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what objects you're trying to pass into the flask server and why?  If you are trying to call flask.app.run() somehow, your example is incorrect as that function doesn't take any arguments (besides kwargs).  For canonical usage examples, you might try looking at: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/symbols/python/flask/app/Flask/run

Comment: I suggest using flask's global variable `g`.

Comment: added a better example

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using SQL server 2012?  I believe you can get a free license using BizSpark.  It is the answer to most problems around data.  I recommend creating a stored proc that can store in a table which can then be subsequently read from another language.

Comment: Why would I want to add in sql server?  Its all in python, would think there would be way to pass already instantiate objects into flask.  Provided a better example above.